# How to achieve local fields grouping in Storm topology?

Tags: apache-storm

I am wondering if the below features available for Storm topologies or
there are hooks that can simulate them:

1. Local Fields grouping.  There is Local Shuffle grouping. Local Fields
   grouping may also be a very useful feature for some use cases where we
   don't want tuple movements across worker as far as possible, but also keeping
   benefits of fields grouping. I made changes in the Storm 0.9.0.1 code base
   (non-apache) for this and it seems to be working
2. Ability to cancel tuples explicitly by Spouts
3. Ability to query the state of a tuple (by its object id)
4. Time-to-live property of tuples.  The framework should throw away
   any tuple that not processed within the time-to-live period

These features may be helpful in certain use cases. Or the features may be already there. Any clarifications greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of unrelated questions here, with very little context (i.e. what are you trying to accomplish). Consider separating them out and filling in more details about your use case for these.

Comment: For me this grouping also makes sens. If, for example, you use kafka spouts and your data is already partitioned, then you would, in theory, be able to reduce the field grouping at worker level, which would save a lot of comminication time and hence provide more throughput. Right?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Local Fields Grouping doesn't really make a lot of sense. Fields grouping means that all the tuples emitted with the same values for the given fields will be processed by the same instance of the recipient bolt. Local implies that if there is a local copy of the given bolt, it should be preferred. The two concepts don't really fit together.

2 - I'm not that familiar with storm's internals, but I don't see how this would work. each bolt that receives a tuple would produce more tuples. Those tuples can be linked back to their "parent" tuple building a tree back to the original. the ability to "cancel" a tuple would required (I guess) being able to mark all the children of the tuple so that any new tuples produced would not be processed.

3 - See previous answer, tracking this state and exposing it would probably add a lot of overhead to storm

4 - See the section on reliability in https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html. Implementing the fail method on a reliable spout could achieve something like this, but only for the original tuple emitted by the spout.

Comment: Local fields grouping will be useful the same way local Shuffle grouping is. Let us say, I want to reduce network IO across workers as far as possible and also want all tuples emitted with same fields values are processed by the same task of the recipient. Then local fields grouping is useful.

Comment: Yes. Cancelling a tuple tree may not be trivial. That is why I was asking if there is a way to do that as I am not aware of that. Right now, we depend on the "fail" method in Spout even for timeouts. There is no easy way to know who is failing and if the failure is for time-out. I have used a work around by using memcache for registering detailed failure information. But in case of timeout, this doesn't help and replay of the tuple may not help as the tuple may timeout again.

Comment: For a local fields grouping, what happens when two bolts on two systems want to send a tuple with matching fields? local shuffle makes sense, it's basically saying "I don't care who gets this, so if there's someone near by give it to them" fields grouping is saying "All the tuples that look like this MUST go to the same recipient", I just don't see how you could add ", so if there's someone near by give it to them" to the latter statement and have it make sense